# CouchDB's erl.exe never idle

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-2.0

As a developer making an app that uses CouchDB for data storage, and working mostly on a laptop I noticed that erl.exe for CouchDB 1.6.1 had the CPU usage at 5% when it was idle (with no connections to it at all, no replication, no pending tasks). With CouchDB 2, idle CPU usage is around 8 to 12%.

Is there anything that I can do to make erl.exe use 0% when idle but running CouchDB?

Maybe lower it a bit?

My CouchDB conf doesn't do anything out of the ordinary, aside from configuring an admin password, and listening on 0.0.0.0.

My current work around is to stop CouchDB when I am not executing the app, and starting back up when executing the app.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there an actual problem this is causing?

Comment: Good question.
The actual problem is that it uses more battery on my laptop. I accept that it's not a huge problem, more like an inconvenience. But I do wonder, what is it doing when it's not doing anything.

Comment: I also have this issue, how to stop it??

Comment: *shrug. I do not know.